# Trying to fill an image with color and making it go down with css

Tags: css

I'm trying to fill this nos bottle then slowly empty it up with css so first the "fill" goes up then slowly slowly drains down, I tried but came with a very terrible result

```css
#bottle, #fill {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.box {
  width: 96px;
  height: 195px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ddd;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #00acee;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 40%;
  animation: fill 1s cubic-bezier(0, 1.62, 0.27, -0.67) infinite;
  z-index: -1;
}

@keyframes fill {
  from {
    top: 250px;
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    top: -50px;
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img id="bottle" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/350561379234873354/813833593084313650/bottle.png" width=100 height=200>
</div>
```

If anyone could point how can i achieve this would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that, but you should consider just left backgroung transparent inside bottom image, outside put a solid color, like black.

```css
#bottle, #fill {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.box {
  width: 96px;
  height: 195px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ddd;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #00acee;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 40%;
  animation: fill 7s cubic-bezier(1, 2.7, 1, -1.7) infinite;
  z-index: -1;
}

@keyframes fill {
  from {
    top: 450px;
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    top: -50px;
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img id="bottle" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/350561379234873354/813833593084313650/bottle.png" width=100 height=200>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely sure what effect you want, but one thing to notice is that you can have the filling and the emptying all in the same animation, without necessarily needing to involve a cubic Bezier function, which in this case seemed to partly fill the bottle, then empty then partly fill but to a different level.

Simplifying things but introducing more detail into the keyframes here's an example of the bottle filling much faster than it empties, by having the percentage of the animation used for filling as much smaller than the emptying.

There are of course many variations on this which can be achieved by having the percentages differ. Also you could reintroduce a cubic Bezier to make the movement less uniform, but that's for your experimentation as I don't know exactly what final effect is wanted.

```html
<head>
<style>

#bottle, #fill {
  /* position: fixed; NOTE. had to change this position fixed to absolute get it to line up on Stack Overflow. Outside SO it was fine as fixed */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
}

.box {
  width: 96px;
  height: 195px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ddd;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #00acee;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 40%;
  /* animation: fill 20s cubic-bezier(0, 1.62, 0.27, -0.67) infinite; */
  animation: fill 20s linear infinite;
  z-index: -1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* added */
}

@keyframes fill {
  0% {
    top: 250px;
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    top: -50px;
    top: 75px;
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
  20% {
   top: 75px;   
   transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
 }
  22% {
   top: 75px;
   transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
 }
  80% {
   transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(360deg);
 }
  
 100% {
   top: 250px;
   transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
  <img id="bottle" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/350561379234873354/813833593084313650/bottle.png" width=100 height=200>
</div>
</body>
```

Note: in the SO snippet system the position fixed had the effect of separating the blob (liquid) from the bottle - it was fine when the code was just run as it was outside the SO system. To demo it here I have made the bottle position absolute and centered the bottle and blob, just so you can get an idea while here. You can remove the absolute and go back to fixed outside SO.

Comment: Very awesome thank you so much, 1 last thing , can i some how fill it to the nozzle of the bottle but anyway i appreciate it , would be nice if we can fill it to the nozzle somehow

Comment: Probably you can do this using a mask - just get the color filling right up instead of stopping where it does now and apply a mask which is basically the bottle in black. Sorry I haven't got time to try it immediately.